# Using Environment Variables for EmailJS Initialization in a Next.js React Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, dotenv, react-fullstack

I'm working on a Next.js project and have implemented a modal popup component that contains a contact form. The contact form is set up to send emails using the emailjs/browser library. Currently, I have the '@emailjs/browser' user ID hard-coded in the component, but I would like to enhance security by using environment variables.

Here's what I've done so far:

Created a .env.local file in the project root directory.
Added the following line in '.env.local', replacing 'your_emailjs_user_id' with the actual EmailJS user ID:
`REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=your_emailjs_user_id`

In the 'ModalPopup' component, I've tried to replace the hard-coded EmailJS initialization with the environment variable like this:

```
import Link from "next/link"
import { strings } from "@/common/strings"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';


export default function ModalPopup({ isContactPopup, handleContactPopup }) {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        subject: "",
        message: "",
      });
    
      const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, [name]: value }));
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Initialize EmailJS with your user ID from environment variable
        emailjs.init(process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID);

        const contactForm = document.querySelector("#contact-form");
        const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
    
        const sendEmail = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          
          const serviceID = "service_zpjx33v";
          const templateID = "template_0vfx7aq";
          
          const inputFields = {
            name: formData.name,
            email: formData.email,
            subject: formData.subject,
            message: formData.message,
          };
          
          emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, inputFields)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log("Email sent successfully:", response);
              // Handle success or show a success message to the user
              submitBtn.innerText = "Done";
              // Clear out all input fields
              setFormData({
                name: "",
                email: "",
                subject: "",
                message: "",
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error sending email:", error);
              // Handle the error, e.g., show an error message to the user
              submitBtn.innerText = "Failed!";
            });
        };
    
        contactForm.addEventListener("submit", sendEmail);
    
        return () => {
          contactForm.removeEventListener("submit", sendEmail);
        };
      },[formData]);
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or if there's a better way to achieve this. When I tried this approach, it didn't work as expected. The Data didn't Received to the Email. from the Contact Form.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly use environment variables for initializing EmailJS in a Next.js React component? Are there any additional steps I should take to make this work? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated!